# I want to change the appearance right or left side of the div with css

Tags: html, css

Im trying to figure out how to solve this but i couldn't find a good option for .

Im trying to describe my problem with 2 pictures.
Im here to learn. Negative reputation doesn't help without saying anything :).

can i do this with pure css or bootstrap??

Also want it responsive.

[First picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNC09.jpg)

[Second Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM5JS.jpg)

Comment: Yes, you can do that with pure CSS. Have you tried anything? :)

Comment: Actually i dont know what i am looking for thats my problem :/ want it to be responsive also.

Comment: You'd want to make use of `overflow` and `transform`, along with absolute-positioning. I'm a little light on time unfortunately, but [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28854907/2341603) is a good example to get you started :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible with pure CSS.
In CSS you have to use **:After** & **:Before** for making shapes that you have mentioned.
For making it responsive simply use **Flex-box grid**.